# How to echo an function

Tags: php, function, echo

I've been struggling to echo the output of a function. I tried this:

```
echo 'myFunction('foo')';
```

.. which obviously won't work, due to the extra single quotes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take this function :

```
function getStr()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

It will simply return a string, which means, calling this :

```
echo getStr();
```

Has the same exact result as calling this :

```
echo "hello";
```

Which means, the result of your function can be treated just like a variable (except you cant modify it), so you can do whatever you want with the result :

```
$string = getStr() . ' - ' . getStr();
echo $string; // Will print "hello - hello";
```

Comment: hmm. I overlooked that. Well, I thought I had an amazing solution. Nevermind then ;p

Answer (score 0):

After trying a little while, I tried calling echo as an function:

```
echo (myFunction('foo'));
```

This works perfectly. I couldn't find this elsewhere on the internet (maybe I'm just a bad googler). Anyways, I thought I could might share this with you guys. In case anyone ever runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo myFunction('foo');
```

Comment: oh. well, I guess I've overlooked that